# How can I eliminate my database"s values for putting to my arrays according to an order?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-database

I have a database for my application.It has 5 different columns. Fifth column name is color.This column has 2 different type of colors.(blue and orange ) Other columns are only data and every data has a color.I want to eliminate my all data to according to these colors.So that I have 3 activities that has custom listview. First one has 2 type colors.There is no problem.But when I passing  to  second activity(only orange) get exception. İnteresting thing that ; İf first activity has only orange type color.It works correctly.When first activity has blue type data, gives me exception. I want to elimination only blue type and send to second activity(only orange type datas).How can I do that ?

```
  while (data.moveToNext()){



            kelimeler_array.add(data.getString(1));
            akli_göz_array.add(data.getString(2));
            kelimelerin_anlamı_array.add(data.getString(3));
            boya_array.add(data.getString(4));      //color array =  boya_array


            for (int i = 0 ; i<boya_array.size(); i++){
                while (boya_array.get(i).equals("#419FEE")){
                    boya_array.remove(i);      //color array =  boya_array
                    kelimeler_array.remove(i);
                    akli_göz_array.remove(i);
                    kelimelerin_anlamı_array.remove(i);


                }

            }

        }
```

Here is my custom listview :

```
 private class Kelimelerim_custom_layout_2_item extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return    kelimeler_array.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return kelimeler_array.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_atolyem_custom_layout_2_item,null);



            TextView kelime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kelime);

            kelime.setText(kelimeler_array.get(position));

            TextView kelimelerin_anlamı = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.anlam);

            kelimelerin_anlamı.setText(kelimelerin_anlamı_array.get(position));

            TextView akli_göz = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ses_benzerliği_text);
            akli_göz.setText(akli_göz_array.get(position));
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(boya_array.get(position)));
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```